# Boolean through prison holes

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to make a boolean on a wall in order for it to pass through the prison door without it showing up, but then continue onto the next door. [image]

Any tips?

Comment: I am not sure what you want and what is your problem. Do you want to union, difference it from the wall? Do you want to make a hole in the shape of those door in the wall? Also if you want to repeat, just duplicate this gate

Comment: I want the use the boolean on the wall so that when it reaches the prison door, it doesnt pass throught it. Basically i want the wall to make holes on the prison door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the non-destructive option:

Forget about using the gate and make a new solid shape with no *Render Visibility* for the *Boolean Modifier*.

[image]

[image]

It should be as simple as possible while following the general shape of the cut you need.  It may be necessary to use a *Subdivision Surface* set to *Simple* on the wall to give it more geometry so the boolean doesn't result in artifacts.

[image]

This is actually not meant to be seen this close up so I haven't worried about the internals here, but you get the idea.

Also worth noting that the *Boolean Modifier* has two *Solver* options.  If one fails, see if the other works better for you.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @HelpWithPrisonProject glad I could help